# How to set a cell background color in source data in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

I am trying to set a cell background color from a data source, which is where the color is determined, in the plain Javascript version of ag-grid. The cell background color will not change based on user input, it will always be determined on the server and returned in a data set for the grid to update. However, I cannot find any parameter in the rowdata object (or anywhere else) that allows me to define a cell-level background color in the grid's source data.

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
var columnDefs = [
  {headerName: "Surname", field: "surname"},
  {headerName: "First name", field: "firstname"},
  {headerName: "Date of Birth", field: "birthdate"},
  {headerName: "House", field: "house"}
];

var rowData = [
  {surname: "Smith" cellbackground=blue, firstname: "John", birthdate: "01/02/2008", house: "Yellow"},
  {surname: "Jones" cellbackground=green, firstname: "Paul", birthdate: "03/05/2008", house: "Green"},
  {surname: "Green" cellbackground=yellow, firstname: "George", birthdate: "28/04/2007", house: "Yellow"},
  {surname: "MacDonald" cellbackground=amber, firstname: "Ringo", birthdate: "14/09/2007", house: "Blue"},
  {surname: "Payne" cellbackground=red , firstname: "David", "02/09/2007", house: "Red"}
];
```

Naturally, this data will come in a JSON file from my web service, but I am unsure of the syntax of including a background color for a specific cell. I want to apply a background color to just the surname cell (for now). I am also aware that the "cellbackground=amber" syntax is not correct. The background colors will not be worked out on the client side, only on the server side, as they are based on rules defined in a server database.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar requirement.  We solved it through using the Adaptable Blotter that is a layer on top of ag-Grid.  We defined the rule there and it then painted ag-Grid accordingly.  Works really well. But ive no idea *how* they do it other than it works.  They call it a Conditional Style if that helps.

Comment: Conditional Styles are designed for when you to style a cell, column, or row when a particular condition or rule is matched; otherwise it will use the default style.  If you want **always** to style a column the use the Format Column function, and if you want **always** to style a row then use RowStyles.  These will both be applied irrespective of the data being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I have now worked this out - I apply a cellStyle to the column to be coloured, based on a separate column that contains the colour name. I have created a function called getCellColor that does this. Hope this is useful to others...

```
var columnDefs = [
{headerName: "HouseColour", field: "housecolour", hide: true},
{headerName: "House", field: "house", width: 100, cellStyle: function getCellColor(params) { return {backgroundColor: params.data.housecolour}}}];

var rowData = [
{house: "Yellow", housecolour: "yellow"},
{house: "Green", housecolour: "green"},
{house: "Purple", housecolour: "purple"},
];
```

Answer (score 0):

We also used the Adaptable Blotter to do this.  They have the ability to do Conditional Styles where the row will update based on data and also simple row styles.